# Error: "Type "string" is not assignable to type "number" " in React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I am creating a React project and using TypeScript/tsx. I have a textarea in one of my components. TypeScript is giving me an error because I specified the number of columns with the string "30" and the number of rows with the string "10". What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Try specifying `columns={30}` instead of `columns="30"` on your component.

Answer (score 0):

In using `<textarea>` you need to use numbers instead of strings.

```
<textarea
    id="txtArea"
    rows={10} 
    cols={30}/>
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense thank you